# Error making http requests. Timeout :: Error and IOError: use_ssl value changed, but session already started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a weird problem that i have a feeling is just a tiny obvious error.

when i make the following implementation ;

```
url = URI.parse(helper.full_url)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
  http.request(req)
}
```

Gives me there error below;

`Timeout :: Error`

But the this implementation;

```
url = URI.parse(helper.full_url)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.request(req)
}
```

gives me this error.

`IOError: use_ssl value changed, but session already started`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use http.use_ssl after Net::HTTP.start, you should use it before. Look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-use_ssl-3D

```
# File net/http.rb, line 591
def use_ssl=(flag)
  flag = (flag ? true : false)
  if started? and @use_ssl != flag
    raise IOError, "use_ssl value changed, but session already started"
  end
  @use_ssl = flag
end
```

try this:

```
uri = URI.parse(helper.full_url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'

http.start do
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  puts http.request(request)
end
```

Comment: I wish to use the result like i had put it here `res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.request(req)
}`